# Why is this IP question off topic?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

[This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/469427/what-exactly-is-the-story-of-ipv9) is about IPv9, asking specifically if there is a history for the famous April Fool's joke and the Chinese adoption story. It was closed as `off topic` in a surprisingly short time by a number of users and no one actually had the politeness to take a little time to comment why they downvoted or voted to close.. I really think the community negative interaction is a very good indication of the bad quality of the question, however, I thought it may be more appropriate to close as `not constructive` or something of the like. Why it was considered off topic? I've read through the FAQ and reviewed some meta question but I really don't get why a question asking about a network protocol history is considered off topic here? What exactly makes it off topic? Isn't `not constructive` more appropriate? (actually I was ready for the `not constructive` with all my arguments!)...

EDIT: I think the question was moderated out of the site.. Thank you all for your interaction...

Comment: If you are ready for not constructive, then make your argument here.  Please tell us why this is a good question that will result in useful information.  Tell us why this is a question for professional system administrators to answer.  (We are not usually protocol designers, that is often developers).  Tell us why this is **practical and answerable**, and **about a problem you face**.  I will easily agree, that maybe another close reason may have been better choice, but I do not agree that this is a useful question for this site.

Comment: I'm trying to update the question but it fails.. moments...

Comment: If you've read meta then you should be aware that we're well and truly fed up with people thinking that we have an obligation to explain down or close votes. **We have no such obligation**, either morally or due to site rules.

Comment: I'm voting to close this. It's not a real question. The OP is just arguing the absurd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"What is the history of IPv4" would be equally off-topic here because its not related to a practical technical problem you'd be facing as an IT professional. This is a good example of the sort of thing that might get some takers for a discussion in chat but which simply isn't going to ever be a good on-topic question for the main site.

Answer (score 14):

Because questions are meant to be based on real problems. This is not a real problem at all, it was a joke and a mistake.

There's nothing to be solved here. The same should apply to "why no ipv5".

Comment: Actually I think both `IPv5` and `IPv9` are valid questions here.. It is on the topic of the site obviously, it deals with the history of a well known network protocol.. Your argument stands if you were talking about `not constructive`, although I can argue more there.. But isin't that on topic anyway??

Comment: @amyassin - so, wait, your problem is the *reason* that was selected when the question was closed..?! If it had been closed as "Not Constructive" you wouldn't mind?

Comment: @amyassin - also, questions about IPv5 are not really on-topic. What problem is there that needs fixing? It would go like this: "Why do we use IPv6 instead of IPv5" Answer: "Does it matter?" - there's no technical problem to be solved. It's not within the realm of the site.

Comment: No, if it was Not constructive I would say something too.. I'm trying to get there...

Comment: So asking anything about history of a protocol or anything not used is off topic on serverfault?? I think that should be clear in the FAQ.. Per the FAQ, my question is On topic; it is about network routing, the history of the most popular network routing protocol..

Comment: @amyassin: Right under the section "What kind of questions should I *not* ask here?": You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. It's even highlighted.

Comment: @kce I actually saw it seconds before you post, and deleted my comment accordingly.. You are right, but still, it is answerable, and it is a problem of understanding.

Comment: @amyassin I'm not sure what part of this is not getting through to you, so I'll offer you an out: Rewrite your question to clarify **exactly what technical problem you, as an IT professional, currently face** and I'll give it honest consideration for reopening.  Note that intellectual curiosity, while admirable, is *not* enough to make a question on-topic for Server Fault -- that is the purview of a research librarian, or Google.

Comment: **You are right, but still, it is answerable, and it is a problem of understanding.** yes - your understanding of what is and is not on topic. "What is the history of IPv4" would be equally off-topic here because its *not related to a practical technical problem you'd be facing as an IT professional*. This is a good example of the sort of thing that *might* get some takers for a discussion in chat but which simply isn't going to ever be a good on-topic question for the main site.

Comment: Thank you @RobM, that actually answered my question.. If you would form it as an answer, I would accept it..